# jupyter_contrib_nbextensions Variable Inspector not storing/displaying variables?

Tags: variables, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I installed and enabled variable inspector [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) but after running my jupyter notebook, some variables did not show up in the variable inspector window. Any idea why or how do I fix this?

For example, after running the following cell, only the variable 'sentence_list' showed up in the variable inspector window:

```
word_list = data.groupby('Sentence #')['Word'].agg(lambda x:list(x))
tag_list = data.groupby('Sentence #')['Tag'].agg(lambda x:list(x))
sentence_list = [list(zip(word, tag)) for (word, tag) in zip(word_list, tag_list)]
```